# Best exception handling practices or recommendations?

Tags: programming-practices, books, exceptions, exception-handling

I think the two main problems with my programs are my code structure/organization and my error handling. I'm reading Code Complete 2, but I need something to read for working with potential problems.

For example, on a website, if something can only happen if the user tampers with data via javascript, do you write for that? Also, when do you not catch errors? When you write a class that expects a string and an int as input, and they aren't a string and int, do you check for that, or do you let it bubble up to the calling method that passed incorrect parameters?

I know this is a broad topic that can't be answered in a single answer here, so what I'm looking for is a book or resource that's commonly accepted as teaching proper exception handling practice.

Comment: what language and development platform are you using?

Comment: I think that "Clean code" has a good chapter about this problem

Comment: What @ElYusubov said. The implementation details and standards of the language/platform you are dealing with have a lot of sway over best practices.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One of the good things to remember is perform exception handling `when there is a need`.

For .NET development platform just follow the MSDN guidelines - [Best Practices for Handling Exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts.aspx), as well as check this nice code-project article - [Exception Handling Best Practices in .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET)

However, the following guidelines are mostly true for any development platform:

- Don't manage business logic with exceptions. Use conditional statements instead. If a control can be done with if-else statement clearly, don't use exceptions because it reduces readability and performance  (e.g. null control, divide by zero control). .
- Exception names must be clear and meaningful, stating the causes of exception.
- Throw exceptions for error conditions while implementing a method. E.g. if you return -1, -2, -3 etc. values instead of FileNotFoundException, that method can not be understand.
- Catch specific exceptions instead of the top Exception class. This will bring additional performance, readability and more specific exception handling.
- Null control with conditionals is not an alternative to catching NullPointerException. If a method may return null, control it with if-else statement. If a return may throw NullPointerException, catch it.
- Try not to re-throw the exception because of the price. Bu if re-throwing had been a must, re-throw the same exception instead of creating a new exception. This will bring additional performance. You may add additional info in each layer to that exception.
- Define your own exception hierarchy by extending current Exception class (e.g. UserException, SystemException and their sub types) and use them. By doing this you can specialize your exceptions and define a reusable module/layer of exceptions. [more to follow in this link](http://codebuild.blogspot.com/2012/01/15-best-practices-about-exception.html)

Comment: Some good general points, though I don't think your 5th point ("Null control with conditionals...") is very clear.

Comment: A couple of good links for Java: http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/11/19/exceptions.html?page=1 http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/04/06/exception-handling-antipatterns.html